# How to prove that $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^Tw\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

How to prove: 
$$\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^Tw\rangle$$
$\langle,\rangle$ represents inner-product, $v,w$ denote vectors and $A$ is a matrix.

Comment: That is false, in general. Check carefully the conditions...

Comment: @DonAntonio Reference for the statement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBqxm4y-Ejg&t=529s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only holds for real valued $A$. In general, the following is true:
$$ \langle A v,w \rangle = \langle v,A^{\mathsf H} w\rangle
$$
where $\mathsf H$ means the conjugate transpose (adjoint) of $A$. This property uniquely defines $A^{\mathsf H}$ from $A$.

To prove your statement, observe that $\langle u,v \rangle = v^\intercal u$. Hence
$$ \langle A v,w \rangle = w^\intercal A v = (A^\intercal w)^\intercal v = \langle v,A^\intercal w \rangle
$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about $n\times n$ *real* matrices.

Hint: Write down everything *component-wise* and use the **definition** of inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

Alternatively, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, assuming one uses column vectors, one has
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=x^Ty
$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.