# Using matrix algebra prove that $ \left< A\textbf{x}, y \right> = \left< \textbf{x}, A^T \textbf{y} \right>$

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an $m \times n$ matrix using matrix algebra prove that $\langle A\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle$ = $\langle \textbf{x}, A^T \textbf{y} \rangle$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

**My approach:** let $m = 2, n = 1$

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   2
\end{pmatrix} $, $ A^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $, $ \textbf{x} = (1)$, $\textbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$

Then

$A\textbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\2 \end{pmatrix}$

$\langle A\textbf{x}, y \rangle = 1*2 + 2*3 = 8$

$A^T\textbf{y} = 8 $

$\langle \textbf{x}, A^T \textbf{y} \rangle = 8 $

$\langle A\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle$ = $\langle \textbf{x}, A^T \textbf{y} \rangle$

However I'm pretty sure this answer isn't satisfactory. What can I do to improve it?

Comment: How is $\langle x,y\rangle$ defined?  Just as $x^Ty$?

Comment: A theorem cannot be proved by example. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063967/proof-of-inner-products-av-w-v-atw/2063971#2063971

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\langle x,y\rangle = x^Ty$ (as the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Inner_product) suggests), we have that:
\begin{align*}
\langle Ax,y\rangle & = (Ax)^Ty \\
& = x^TA^Ty \\
& = (x^T)(A^Ty) \\
& = \langle x,A^Ty\rangle
\end{align*}
Here, we had to use that:
$$(AB)^T = B^TA^T$$
A proof of this can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Transpose_of_Matrix_Product), which I can explain if it doesn't make sense.